# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm having a problem related to cors, I can't get rid of famous

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load external domain.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access

What I tried:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/  - End-to-End Example , still doesnt work , getting the same error.
- https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299915-How-to-make-an-ajax-request-cross-origin-CORS
- other various examples

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'http://updates.html5rocks.com';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

Example above only works in launching static html when I upload it to main domain I'm getting error which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I just found how to do it with http://cors.io/  .

http://cors.io/?u=http:(your url without brackets)

WORKS LIKE A CHARM.

THANK YOU TO EVERYONE WHO CONTRIBUTED.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on  your server Access-control-allow-origin is set to *
Assuming lets say its nodejs

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

```
// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
```

});

Comment: And how can i do that?

Comment: im kinda new to this.

Comment: Anyone could help?